# IE9 ASP MVC4 back button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 web api. When I first wrote the program and generated help files using HelpConfig, everything was fine. I had to change one of the function names and I rebuilt the program. The help file seems to have cached help files only in IE9. When I use back button I see my old function definition but when I press refresh button, I get new function definition.This does not happen in chrome. I changed the browser settings to (Temp internet files -> check for newwer versions of stored paged to verytime I visit the webpage). And in the controller, for the function that i modified I added

```
 [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

How can I  address this problem?
Thanks

Comment: "When I use back button I see my old function definition but when I press refresh button, I get new function definition." So IE9 is now showing the updated page that you would expect? What's the issue?

Comment: Don't you mean `OutputCacheLocation.None`?

Comment: Certainly @MarkRotteveel ...at least not in the `Client`.

Comment: @ChrisHardie, I do not want users to press F5 to get the correct page

Comment: Oops! sorry yep I changed my code

Comment: What are you decorating with the `OutputCache` attribute? The Web API action? What is this "help file"? An MVC web page?

Comment: It is a MVC 4 help file generated using this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages